# How to redirect to the next html page's class on buttonclick in html

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have thumbnail images in first.html page and sliding images in second.html, if clicked on the particular image it should be redirected to a new page where the image is again displayed along with some information about it from the second.html. 
i have done coding as below, but it navigates to second.html page correctly not to the particular sliding class by default always displays the first page of the slider. i'm new to html and javascript, dont know why its not redirecting the below given class. please help me.

```
    <li><a href='second.html' class='.pink-slide'><img src="images/thumb/a.jpg" alt="Image a" /></a></li>
    <li><a href='second.html' class='.blue-slide'><img src="images/thumb/b.jpg" alt="Image b" /></a></li>
```

Comment: Why both anchors having `href='second.html'`?

Comment: Both of the links you posted will navigate to the top of second.html page. If you add anchors to your images, you can direct the browser to go to a specific point of the second.html page. However if your images are part of a slider then you need to work with js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an [id](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/a/href) attribute in `href` tag if you want to point to a particular part on an html page.
I am guessing here this is what you want. You want your link to point to a particular div on the page 'second.html' right?
If so do the following,
On `second.html`,

```
<a id="pink-slide">&nbsp;</a>
  Your sliding image content
```

and then in your link,

```
<li><a href='second.html#pink-slide'><img src="images/thumb/a.jpg" alt="Image a" /></a></li>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer it works fine, but if i click on 3rd image it takes to the 3rd sliding page, i'm able to slide the screen right but could not slide the page to left. do you know why? @redDevil

Comment: can you show me the markup which you have written? a jsfiddle perhaps. see http://jsfiddle.net/